# Trouble with downloading ACS data using the lodown package, as per the asdfree code

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to use the asdfree (http://asdfree.com/american-community-survey-acs.html) code to use the data from the American Community Survey in R. I had trouble installing the lodown package because it was outdated, but after reading this page (https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown/issues/164) I thought I had been able to fix it. But I still get this error when I try to download the microdata to my local computer:

```
> acs_cat <- lodown( "acs" , acs_cat )
locally downloading acs

arguments 'show.output.on.console', 'minimized' and 'invisible' are for Windows only
sh: 7za: command not found
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lodown_0.1.0      Hmisc_5.0-1       devtools_2.4.5    usethis_2.1.6     janitor_2.2.0     sjmisc_2.8.9      data.table_1.14.8
 [8] lubridate_1.9.2   forcats_1.0.0     stringr_1.5.0     dplyr_1.1.2       purrr_1.0.1       readr_2.1.4       tidyr_1.3.0      
[15] tibble_3.2.1      ggplot2_3.4.2     tidyverse_2.0.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fs_1.6.2          bit64_4.0.5       httr_1.4.5        insight_0.19.1    rprojroot_2.0.3   tools_4.2.3       profvis_0.3.7    
 [8] backports_1.4.1   utf8_1.2.3        R6_2.5.1          sjlabelled_1.2.0  rpart_4.1.19      colorspace_2.1-0  nnet_7.3-18      
[15] urlchecker_1.0.1  withr_2.5.0       tidyselect_1.2.0  gridExtra_2.3     prettyunits_1.1.1 processx_3.8.1    bit_4.0.5        
[22] curl_5.0.0        compiler_4.2.3    rvest_1.0.3       cli_3.6.1         htmlTable_2.4.1   xml2_1.3.3        desc_1.4.2       
[29] labeling_0.4.2    scales_1.2.1      checkmate_2.2.0   callr_3.7.3       digest_0.6.31     foreign_0.8-84    rmarkdown_2.21   
[36] base64enc_0.1-3   pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.5   sessioninfo_1.2.2 fastmap_1.1.1     htmlwidgets_1.6.2 rlang_1.1.0      
[43] rstudioapi_0.14   shiny_1.7.4       farver_2.1.1      generics_0.1.3    vroom_1.6.1       magrittr_2.0.3    Formula_1.2-5    
[50] Rcpp_1.0.10       munsell_0.5.0     fansi_1.0.4       lifecycle_1.0.3   stringi_1.7.12    snakecase_0.11.0  pkgbuild_1.4.0   
[57] plyr_1.8.8        grid_4.2.3        parallel_4.2.3    promises_1.2.0.1  crayon_1.5.2      miniUI_0.1.1.1    hms_1.1.3        
[64] knitr_1.42        ps_1.7.5          pillar_1.9.0      reshape2_1.4.4    pkgload_1.3.2     glue_1.6.2        evaluate_0.20    
[71] remotes_2.4.2     vctrs_0.6.2       tzdb_0.3.0        httpuv_1.6.9      gtable_0.3.3      cachem_1.0.7      xfun_0.39        
[78] mime_0.12         xtable_1.8-4      later_1.3.0       memoise_2.0.1     cluster_2.1.4     timechange_0.2.0  ellipsis_0.3.2   


lodown is now exiting due to an installation error.


Error in load_fun(data_name = data_name, catalog, ...) : 
  you need to install 7-zip.  if you already have it, include a path_to_7za='/directory/7za' parameter
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste0("\"", path_to_7za, "\" -h"), show.output.on.console = FALSE) :
  error in running command
```

I wanted to download the ACS microdata to my computer, but I think the asdfree code is outdated, so I am having trouble getting it to work. I tried using the help from this page https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown/issues/164 and still was not able to download the data.